# wrong images are displaying first and then correct images are displaying during scrolling of listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

> I am using listview with images in my application.But whenever I
>   scroll the list the wrong images are shown first and then the correct
>   images are displaying.I dont know why it is happening like this.I
>   think already loaded images are displaying until the position is set. 
>   Here is my adapter class,please help me where I am going wrong

```
  public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> namear,msgar,idar,profimage,postimage,commentsnum,objectid,urlString;
  ImageLoader imageLoader;
  Bitmap[] bitdata;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Activity c,int i,ArrayList<String> postpic, ArrayList<String> names,ArrayList<String> msg,ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> proimg,Bitmap[] bit,ArrayList<String> comment,ArrayList<String> objid,ArrayList<String> web) {

      super(c, i, names);
    Log.e("adapter","adap");
    this.context = c;
    this.namear = names;
    this.msgar = msg;
    this.idar = id;
    this.profimage=proimg;
    this.postimage=postpic;
    this.bitdata=bit;
    this.commentsnum=comment;
    this.objectid=objid;
    this.urlString=web;
   this.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View rowView=convertView;
  ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
      if(convertView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
  rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.walldata, null);

  holder.name1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
  holder.message1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
  holder.profimg= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
  holder.postimg= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picpost);
  holder.comments = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
  rowView.setTag(holder);
     Log.e("user",idar.get(position));
      }
      else
         {
          holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
         }
    Log.e("adapter","adap");
    holder.name1.setText(namear.get(position));
    if(msgar.get(position)!=""){
        holder.message1.setText(msgar.get(position));

    }
    else
    {
        holder.message1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(!postimage.get(position).equals(""))
    {try{
         imageLoader.DisplayImage(postimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"), holder.postimg) ;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    else
    {
         holder.postimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    try{
      imageLoader.DisplayImage(profimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"), holder.profimg) ;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.comments.setText(commentsnum.get(position)+"\t"+"Comments");
    holder.comments.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myintent=new Intent(Wall.this,Comments.class);
            myintent.putExtra("name", namear.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("profimg", profimage.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("message", msgar.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("postpic", postimage.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("objectid", objectid.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("commentsnum",commentsnum.get(position));
            myintent.putExtra("webservice", urlString.get(position));
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });

    return rowView;
  }

}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView name1, message1,comments;
    ImageView profimg,postimg;
}
```

Comment: if someone is still looking for an answer - try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049785/listview-showing-wrong-view-for-a-few-seconds-while-flinging-and-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the image in your ImageView to null as early as possible in your getView method. Since the ListView is re-using list items, the old one will be displayed until a new one has been set.

Comment: And when I scroll down and then up,the already loaded images are not displaying and it is taking time to display

Comment: If you are downloading the images, you should implement a cache to avoid downloading them every single time they are displayed. Just reading them locally and setting them to the ImageView is fast.

Comment: I worked in different approach by not taking any of these holder classes and nothing ,I am getting outofmemory error with bitmap size exceeds vm budget during fast scrolling of listview

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to your question above. You can still have the same approach, using the holder class, just adding a cache and making sure to remove the old image to avoid seeing it before the new image is loaded when scrolling. Maybe I don't fully understand what your problem is.