# Loading the correct Image in List View

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I'm making an app that displays images from urls in a listview. I use a asynctask to get the image and place it into the imageviews. The way I currently have it is that an asynctask is called in the getview method. The do in background part gets the image from the url. The problem I'm having is when I scroll to an element in the listview, initially the wrong image is there but the correct image is quickly loaded. Why is this happening?

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your list row layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are setting your ImageView to null as soon as you declare it. It's hard to tell without knowing what the image is, but it's possible that the ListView is reusing old images. Reference below:

[wrong images are displaying first and then correct images are displaying during scrolling of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394724/wrong-images-are-displaying-first-and-then-correct-images-are-displaying-during)